# AWS fargate: Wait for set amount of seconds before starting second container

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

AWS fargate: Wait for set amount of seconds before starting second container

Im testing to set up a proof-of-concept app in AWS fargate that uses two different containers. The idea is for container A to work as bridge over TCP to a interface with a server and then container B should start up and use this bridge to communicate with the server.

When I start container A it takes about 30 seconds after the status is changed to “RUNNING” for it to fully initialize and have the bridge working. And I need this bridge to be fully initialized before I can start container B.

Is there some way to configure the task definition so it waits a set amount of time after the status of container A has changed before trying to start container B?
I have tried using the standard health-check with pining the tcp port, but when I ping it I’m only getting error 52.

Currently the easiest way I see is to just put a simple sleep between the start-ups just to see if it works.

So to summarize my question: Is it possible to put a simple wait between two containers when creating a task running on AWS Fargate?

Comment: Did you setup container dependency in the task definition? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_ContainerDependency.html

Comment: Yes, the problem is that when container A says it has started it still needs about 30 seconds to fully initialize everything

Comment: Using ECS container dependency, you could add a dummy container C, that runs after A and sleeps 30s. Then when C is SUCCESS, B starts.